# How to resolve jasper 1.8.0 dependency into Grails 4?

Tags: dependencies, jasper-reports, grails-4

I've successfully installed `jasper 1.8.0` into `build.gradle`. However, after installation, I'm getting this error.

My project developed by Grails 4 with java 11

**Error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.8.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.8.0/jasper-1.8.0.pom
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.8.0/jasper-1.8.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.grails.plugins:jasper:1.8.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.8.0/jasper-1.8.0.pom
       - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/jasper/1.8.0/jasper-1.8.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 4 and above, don't use Jasper 1.8.0; hence add the following dependency under `build.gradle`:

```json
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:jasper:2.1.0'
}
```